# Python - Can't find the right class for a button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium, and self training.
At the moment I'm trying to get some airline data from Ryanair website, but am not able to progress when the cookies pop up appears in the screen.

In particular, I want to click on button Done ("Fatto" in italian - The yellow one in the screen1[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHTCL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ8cz.png)), but I think that I'm not choosing the right class.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import  Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver))
driver.maximize_window()
link= "https://www.ryanair.com/it/it"
driver.get(link)
sleep(3)
cookies  = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'cookie-popup-with-overlay__button-settings').click()
sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,'cookies-details__done-button ry-button--gradient-yellow ng-star-inserted'))).click()
```

I tried also with this code, but the same error was shown

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import  Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver))
driver.maximize_window()
link= "https://www.ryanair.com/it/it"
driver.get(link)
cookies  = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'cookie-popup-with-overlay__button-settings').click()
sleep(10)
driver.find_element(BY.CLASS_NAME,'cookies-details__allow-all-button ry-button--gradient-blue ng-star-inserted').click
```

Answer (score 1):

If you notice <kbd>Fatto</kbd> button's HTML, it is wrapped within an [IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77914589/7598774). In such cases, you need to first switch inside IFRAME and then perform the actions.

Check the working code below with in-line explanation:

```
link= "https://www.ryanair.com/it/it"
driver.get(link)
driver.maximize_window()

# Create WebDriver wait object with wait time of 10s
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Click on Visualizza impostazioni cookie button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Visualizza impostazioni cookie']"))).click()

# below line will switch driver context inside the IFRAME
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='cookie-preferences__iframe']")));

# below line will click on `Fatto` button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()=' Fatto ']"))).click()

# below line will come out of IFRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```